# unable to display auto complete places when using overflow-x in html

Tags: html, css

In my site i'm using google auto complete to display places.

Issue is, I've added `overflow-x: hidden` to `html` to avoid shaking while scrolling in mobile devices.

But using `overflow-x: hidden` for some reason google place is not displaying while searching in the text box.

My website address

https://daynightdroptaxichennai.web.app/

Please help.

Comment: I can see the autocomplete both on phone and on pc

Comment: yes, you add the overflow hidden  to html and check

Comment: it's shaking in mobile view, if i add overflow hidden shaking stops. but auto complete is not displaying

Answer (score 0):

Adding

```
body > app-root > app-home > app-booking > section > div > div{
    overflow-x : hidden;
}
```

should fix your problem

Testing on your website, seems like that you can also add that property to only the form, and it fixes your problem

Comment: @Arun there is something going on when the website loads, because if i disable that property it doesn't work, and if you delete it and i add it after the website is loaded, it works fine.. can you please try using document.queryselector()... at the end of your document? (using jquery would be document.ready)